# Disappearing tables in rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I have some tables missing from the rails_admin interface. sometimes they appear and disappear when refreshing the page. this happens in development and production.

I'm using rails 3.0.9 and rails_admin from 3.0 branch
When looking at the logs, it seems this query returns wrong data sometimes :

```
SELECT name
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
```

Any suggestions on how to investigate this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a regression in rails_admin :
http://groups.google.com/group/rails_admin/browse_thread/thread/8c15daf46953a046

adding the following code to the models solves the symptom

```
  rails_admin do 
    visible { true } 
  end
```